# Create xl/access like cells in c# forms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

How would i go about creating xl/access like cells in a c# winforms ?
(which gui controls )

Comment: Could you describe what features you are looking for in the cell

Comment: well i want to be able to display any number of collums and rows within a specific region and to load sql database tables into these cells.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend DataGrid, right down there in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SourceGrid in a number of projects

http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/

It provides good flexibility, and is open source.

Comment: unfortunately no vs 2010 support

Comment: @Joe: It works great in VS 2010... do you mean design time support?